# Prepared Statement MySQL UPDATE Not Updating the DB Values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a script to update the values stored in the DB with the new values typed in the form

GET the values from the form:

```
$reviewTitle = $_POST['reviewTitle'];
$storeScore = $_POST['storeScore'];
$reviewContent = $_POST['reviewContent'];
```

UPDATE Values to the DB

```
$sql = "UPDATE reviews SET reviewTitle=?, storeScore=?, reviewContent=? WHERE reviewID=?";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('sisi', $reviewTitle, $storeScore, $reviewContent, $_POST['edit']);

$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->error) {
  echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
}
else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";

header("Location: review?store=" . $store['storeName']);
```

I cannot see a reason why this would not work, am i missing something in the syntax? Any help appreciated

EDIT: I have added the Error that is outputted by the script

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method 
PDOStatement::bind_param() in . 
/home/o2q4e1ph6yl2/public_html/editreview.php:38 Stack trace: #0 
/home/o2q4e1ph6yl2/public_html/review.php(54): include() #1 {main} . 
thrown in /home/o2q4e1ph6yl2/public_html/editreview.php on line 38
```

Comment: Hi, who ever down voted my question, please could you give guidance how to improve next time ? What is wrong with my question ?

Comment: @misorude I added the following: if ($stmt->error) {
   echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
 }
 else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows"; However no error is outputted leading me to believe there is issue with the syntax

Comment: @misorude There is nothing wrong with using real_escape_string along with a prepared statement, i do it as a precaution to all data moved between pages

Comment: @misorude Error checking has been added to the question as requested

Comment: @bradders _"There is nothing wrong with using real_escape_string along with a prepared statement,"_ . Apart from it being entirely pointless, because the parameterisation takes care of the escaping for you already. In fact if you double-escape things in this way, there's a chance you'll end up with unexpected results.

Comment: _"However no error is outputted"_ ...that is probably because you immediately issue a header instructing the browser to redirect to another page, so it never bothers to show the output from this script. Either log the output to a log file on disk instead (so you can then check it later), or temporarily remove the redirect so you can test properly. Probably in the final version, in the case of a catastrophic error it would be better for the redirect not to take place, and instead the app should show an error screen to the user, so they know a problem has occurred.

Comment: @ADyson The Header does not run, i only put it in the question to show what i want to happen, even if i remove the header no error is outputted

Comment: I guess no one knows the answer, thats why they are just pointing out other things just to put a comment rather than an answer,

Comment: @braddders _“There is nothing wrong with using real_escape_string along with a prepared statement”_ - of course there is. If I enter `Foo " Bar`, and you store that as `Foo \" Bar`, then you have falsified the data.

Comment: "The Header does not run, i only put it in the question to show what i want to happen"...please don't add things which aren't part of the actual code - you need to show us something which reproduces the issue, instead of leading us down a different track. We can't answer you yet because there isn't enough information yet - hence us making suggestions to you. Either that or perhaps you're implying it doesn't run because the code never gets to that line? If so then you need to discover where it stops executing...

Comment: So if no redirect is occurring, and no output is given at all, then that maybe suggests that the page is crashing before that. What do you actually see instead? Blank page? Some other output? Tell us what _is_ happening, instead of what's _not_ happening, that way we can get a better idea. Also, what debugging have you done? You should be able to use either a debugger (if you've got XDebug), or at least some var_dump() statements to verify what path your code is taking. Your browser tools might also help you to see what's happening to the HTTP request.

Comment: P.S. It's entirely possible for errors to occur prior to the execute command - both prepare() and bind_param() can also produce errors. So error checking needs to be all the way through.

Comment: An easier way to see mysqli errors though is to make it generate an exception instead. For thoroughness, enable all PHP and mysqli error reporting like this: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors. (So if the error occurs somewhere else that's not related to the SQL, then you'll see that too)

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for showing me how to output the errors, i did not know there was a global way to turn off/on error reporting

Comment: The following is the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in /home/o2q4e1ph6yl2/public_html/editreview.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /home/o2q4e1ph6yl2/public_html/review.php(54): include() #1 {main} thrown in /home/o2q4e1ph6yl2/public_html/editreview.php on line 38

Comment: Ah so you're using PDO, not mysqli. In PDO the method is called [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) not bind_param . And the syntax for using it is totally different, so you'd better look at the examples on that page. Always pays to read the manual...

Comment: P.S. you can actually turn the error reporting on and off (and control the level of detail) in your php.ini file as well, so it applies to all scripts on the server. You can also enable automatic logging of exceptions to a file for consulting later (this is good in a live environment, instead of exposing the error details on screen, which can be a security risk). Again check the manual for details.

Comment: @ADyson I have changed it to bindParam however the UPDATE statement does not function, however the errors have now gone.The output is now Updated Rows which is odd, as they was not updated

Comment: As I said in my comment above, as well as a different name, the syntax for usage is totally different, so please read the examples in the manual page I linked you to in that comment. You can't possibly have had time to do that, given the speed of your response. If you've stuck with the current syntax I'd be surprised if the bindParam() statement wasn't failing. To get PDO (rather than mysqli) to throw exceptions in all cases, you might have to take [extra steps](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)..alternatively, inspect the error message directly after running bindParam

Comment: @ADyson I have now sorted the issue, answer below, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question is:

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE reviews SET reviewTitle=:reviewTitle, storeScore=:storeScore, reviewContent=:reviewContent WHERE reviewID=:reviewID");

$query->execute(array(':reviewTitle' => $reviewTitle, ':storeScore' => 
$storeScore, ':reviewContent' => $reviewContent, ':reviewID' => $reviewID));
```

It only took 4h to figure out